# Stretch WPF grid horizontally inside RibbonGroup

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon, alignment

How do I stretch a WPF `Grid` horizontally inside a `RibbonGroup`? It's not stretching despite the `HorizontalAlignment` property.

```
<Window x:Name="FrmMain" x:Class="PhotoCell.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="PhotoCell" Height="386.821" Width="757.701" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imgMain" Margin="10,142,10,9"/>
    <Ribbon VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <RibbonTab Header="Home" Height="88" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <RibbonGroup Header="Save/Load" Height="88" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="cmdLoadImage" Background="#FFFFC500" Label="Load" Click="cmdLoadImage_Click" Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="cmdSaveImage" Background="#FFFFC500" Label="Save" Click="cmdSaveImage_Click" Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </Grid>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I've also tried adding

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

After the row definitions.

Comment: I've tried adding `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />` to no avail.

Comment: can you show the code with <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />?

Comment: Updated the question. The modifications should be crystal clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `HorizontalAlignment` and the `HorizontalContentAlignment` properties aren't performing as they should - might be a bug in the ribbon's control templates.

Anyway, there is a workaround: you could bind the `RibbonGroup` and `Grid` to the `RibbonTab's` `ActualWidth` property. You might need to use a converter to fine tune these values with an offset, but all in all, it does the trick:

```
<Ribbon VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <RibbonTab x:Name="tab" Header="Home" Height="88" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <RibbonGroup Width="{Binding ElementName=tab, Path=ActualWidth}" Header="Save/Load" Height="88" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=tab, Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RibbonButton x:Name="cmdLoadImage" Background="#FFFFC500" Label="Load" Click="cmdLoadImage_Click" Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <RibbonButton x:Name="cmdSaveImage" Background="#FFFFC500" Label="Save" Click="cmdSaveImage_Click" Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </Grid>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

Comment: However, there is one discrepancy, which I think you should edit. I need the `RibbonGroup` to be `90` pixels wide.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have a `RibbonGroup` streched inside a `Ribbon`. I used a different approach. Since I had to do some calculation (get the width of all other RibbonGroups), I didn't use a Binding with a Converter. Within a Converter I cannot reach the other controls easily. I used the `SizeChanged` event of the `Ribbon`. Here I set the width of the `RibbonGroup`:

```
    private void RibbonOnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs sizeChangedEventArgs)
    {
        ChangeWidgetsGroupWidth(sizeChangedEventArgs.NewSize.Width);
    }

    private void ChangeWidgetsGroupWidth(double newRibbonWidth)
    {
        double otherRibbonGroupWidths = 0;
        foreach (RadRibbonGroup item in HomeTab.Items)
        {
            if (item != rgWidgetsGroup)
            {
                otherRibbonGroupWidths += item.ActualWidth + 2; // Extra margin between groups
            }
        }
        double width = newRibbonWidth - otherRibbonGroupWidths - 6; // '6' to add extra margin
        rgWidgetsGroup.Width = width > 0 ? width : 0;
    }
```

`rgWidgetsGroup` is the `RibbonGroup` I wanted to have the maximum size. I think it would be easy to do something similar for a `Control` inside a `RibbonGroup`.